How can I avoid "scroll-snapping backwards" on Chrome mobile?
I'm trying to create a website with three full pages where the user smoothly scrolls between them. I've used a hacky solution found online to ensure that these pages have the appropriate height (full) regardless of whether or not the address bar is visible. However, this means that the height of the pages does change when I scroll, in particular when the address bar vanishes or reappears. This seems (per this question, which diagnoses the problem but wasn't able to help me resolve it) to be the source of an issue I'm having: sometimes, when I scroll most of the way up from the 3rd slide to the 2nd or the 2nd slide to the 1st, Chrome snaps "backwards" (despite upwards being the more sensible option).
Here's a demo: https://robintruax.github.io/ Playing around with it on a mobile device (tested on Chrome) should illustrate the issue.
The code (very minimal) is here: https://github.com/RobinTruax/robintruax.github.io
I am not sure how to avoid this issue (I tried to figure out the solution in the question, but could not adapt it) and would love any insight.


let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
});

window.addEventListener('touchmove', () => {
  let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
});

// Constants
book = document.querySelector(".book");
scrollbar = document.querySelector("#scrollbar");

// Scrollbar
book.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  // setTimeout(function(){
  //     alert(scrollbar.style.height);
  // }, 5000);
  scrollbar.style.top = (window.innerHeight * book.scrollTop / book.scrollHeight).toString() + "px";
  scrollbar.style.height = (window.innerHeight * window.innerHeight / book.scrollHeight).toString() + "px";
});
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.book {
  height: 100vh;
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Scrolling */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.page {
  height: 100vh;
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
  width: 100%;
  /* Scrolling */
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
}

.book::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
}

#p1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#p2 {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

#p3 {
  background-color: lightgray;
}


/* Insert Custom Scrollbar */

#scrollbar {
  /* Sizing */
  height: 33.3vh;
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 33.3);
  width: 6px;
  /* Layout */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  /* Visual */
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
<!-- Home Page -->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Header -->
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!-- Metadata -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <article class="book">
    <section class="page" id="p1">
    </section>

    <section class="page" id="p2">
    </section>

    <section class="page" id="p3">
    </section>
  </article>

  <div id="scrollbar"></div>

  <script src="resize.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




Please check Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it? (minimal reproductible example using the <> button).

Hi Cedric, this is a minimal reproducible example. I've trimmed down the actual code of the website into a handful of lines and uploaded it because it's difficult to describe the bug.

[...] The primary goal of Stack Overflow is to build an archive of questions and answers that are useful to people and situations beyond that of the person who asked the question originally. A question with just a link to code subverts this goal. [...], from Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?. I added a snippet in your question
